# Factory Method with Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have two different types of item: Picture and Video. In order to manage them, I have created an interface and two classes which implement it

```
public interface Item{
}

public class ItemPicture: Item{
}

public class ItemVideo: Item {
}
```

Now I have some classes to manage that items, that inherit from a manager interface

```
public interface ItemManager<T>{
   IList<T> FGetByGroup(string idgroup);
}

public class ItemManagerPictures : IItemManager<ItemPicture>{
   public IList<ItemFoto> FGetByGroup(string idgroup){
      ...
   }
}
public class ItemManagerVideos: IItemManager<ItemVideo>{
   public IList<ItemVideo> FGetByGroup(string idgroup){
      ...
   }
}
```

In order to have a factory method which creates the appropriate object, I have created this class

```
public class ItemManagerCreator
    {
        public static IItemManager<Item> MakeItemManager(string type)
        {
            IItemManager<Item> objMgr = null;

            switch (type)
            {
                
                case "Picture":
                    objMgr = (IItemManager<Item>)new ItemManagerPictures();
                    break;

                case "Video":
                    objMgr = (IItemManager<Item>)new ItemManagerVideos();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return objMgr ;

        }
    }
```

From the controller I want to do this

```
var type="Picture";

IItemManager<Item> itemMgr = ItemManagerCreator.MakeItemManager(type);
var itemList = itemMgr.FGetByGroup(string idgroup);
```

But I get this casting error

> Can't convert from type '...ItemManagerPictures' to type  '...IItemManager`1[...Item]'.

which makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but after 1000 turns, I think the problem is with the factory method and generics, which is not well designed.

I'm new to design patterns, and maybe I'm not applying the right one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note how, if that could work, you could do `itemList.Add(new ItemVideo())` and add video into the list of pictures. Do you actually need for the return type of `FGetByGroup` to be `IList`, and you going to add items there?

Comment: You are right... I'm not going to add items, just read them in a foreach, and since all them are of type Item, show its common properties, no matter if they are Pictures or Videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work as is, because `ItemManagerPictures` and `ItemManagerVideos` are indeed not convertible to `IItemManager<Item>`, check [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) to see why.

In this case, because you actually do not need to use `IList` as return type of `FGetByGroup` (as figured out in comments), you can make it work by using some interface which is covariant in generic type `T` (such as `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`) and then declare your type `T` as [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) too:

```
public interface IItemManager<out T>{
    IReadOnlyList<T> FGetByGroup(string idgroup);
}

public class ItemManagerPictures : IItemManager<ItemPicture>{
    public IReadOnlyList<ItemPicture> FGetByGroup(string idgroup) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, `ItemManagerPictures` is assignable to `IItemManager<Item>` so your code will work without exceptions.

Comment: Works like a charm. I didn't know about covariance, but I have it clear now. As soon as I read your comment about adding a video to the pictures list I realized something was wrong there. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From your code you seem to know beforehand what type of ItemManager you want, so you can do something like this :

```
public class ItemManagerCreator
{
    public static IItemManager<T> MakeItemManager<T>() where T : Item
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ItemPicture))
        {
            return (IItemManager<T>)new ItemManagerPictures();
        }

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ItemVideo))
        {
            return (IItemManager<T>)new ItemManagerVideos();
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

And for use :

```
string groupId = string.Empty;
dynamic itemManager = null;
```

I want an `IItemManager` for pictures

```
itemManager = ItemManagerCreator.MakeItemManager<ItemPicture>();
IList<ItemPicture> pictures = itemManager.FGetByGroup(groupId);
```

Then I want an `IItemManager` for videos

```
itemManager = ItemManagerCreator.MakeItemManager<ItemVideo>();
IList<ItemVideo> videos = itemManager.FGetByGroup(groupId);
```